# How is it possible to pass multiple params into a template in Play 2.0?

Tags: java, templates, parameters, rendering, playframework-2.0

i want to render to my template 2 things at the same time like this:

```
String one = "one"; 
String two = "two";
return ok(template.render(one,two));
```

but Playframework says, it is wrong. how is it possible to render 2 values at the same time then? should i save them into a list? but then i have to unpack it again in my template.. :(

please help! appreciate any help!

Comment: solved, thanks to Marcus, that code above is fine..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Play templates in 2.0 are just Scala functions, so you need to declare params at the beginning of the template (beginning from line #1):

```
@(one: String, two: String)

This is first param: @one <br/>
This is second param: @two
```

Check the [templates docs](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/JavaTemplates) for details

### Map

On the other way if you need to pass large quantity of variables of the same type then the `Map` can be good solution as well:

```
public static Result index() {

    Map<String, String> labels = new HashMap<String, String>();

    labels.put("first", "First label");
    labels.put("second", "Second label");
    // etc etc
    labels.put("hundredth", "Label no. 100");

    return ok(template.render(labels));
}
```

`template.scala.html`

```
@(labels: Map[String, String])

@labels.get("first") <br/>
@labels.get("second") <br/>
.....
@labels.get("hundredth")
```

### View model

Finally to make things even more typesafe you can create your own `view models` like (sample):

```
package models.view;

import java.util.Date;

public class MyViewModel {

    public String pageTitle = "";
    public Date currentDate = new Date();
    public Integer counter = 0;
    // etc...

}
```

controller:

```
public static Result myActionUsingModel() {
    MyViewModel data = new MyViewModel();
    data.pageTitle = "Ellou' World!";
    data.counter = 123;

    return ok(myViewUsingModel.render(data));
}
```

view:

```
@(data: models.view.MyViewModel)

<h1>@data.pageTitle</h1>

<div>Now is: @data.currentDate</div>
<div>The counter value is: @data.counter</div>
```

Comment: oh that works!, render was looking weird, i thought it is an error.. thanks Marcus!