# How to pass Java object into Play's template? [Play framework 2.0]

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

How can I pass Java object into Play's template? Is it possible?

---

Ok, I found an answer.

```
@(variable : really.super.extremely.long.package.name.ClassName)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is it possible to pass multiple params into a template in Play 2.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272984/how-is-it-possible-to-pass-multiple-params-into-a-template-in-play-2-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was discussed many times and there is many answers on it:

[How is it possible to pass multiple params into a template in Play 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11273097/1066240)